# Logstash, getting remote server name

Tags: logstash, rsyslog

I have a number of ESXi servers forwarding logs to a central loghost. My loghost is running rsyslog. This seems to all be working fine.

The main issue I am having is that Logstash sees every message as coming from the loghost, not the remote ESXi server that sent the log.

The FQDN of the ESXi server is in the message, but what I'd really like is for it to show up as coming from that machine so I can match on [host] and so forth.

A major feature that I need is to be able to match on that name and assign it a tag, like what campus that server is located at.

Haven't really come across a good way to do this with logstash and am beginning to wonder if I need to make this change in my rsyslog.conf instead.

For clarity (simplified), all messages show up as

datestamp loghost "esxiserver.domain.com message"

What I would like is

datestamp esxiserver.domain.com  "message"

Here is my config, pretty simple for the moment just trying to get it to work.

```
input {
    file {
            type => "syslog"
            path => [ "/var/log/rsyslog/**/*.log" ]
            start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      overwrite => "message"
      match => {
         "message" => "^(?:<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>)?%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %
 {@source_host} %{IPORHOST:host} (?:%{PROG:program}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])?: )?%{GR
 EEDYDATA:message}"
      }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp",  "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]

    }
  }
}

filter {
  multiline {
   pattern => "^\s"
   what => "previous"
 }
}

filter {
    multiline {
            pattern => "\\$"
            what => "next"
    }
}

output {
        stdout {
                                    codec => rubydebug
                                }
    #elasticsearch {
    #        cluster => "paoli"
    #}
}
```

Example Output:

```
 "syslog_severity_code" => 5,
"syslog_facility_code" => 1,
     "syslog_facility" => "user-level",
     "syslog_severity" => "notice"
}
{
             "message" => "May 18 00:48:27 lexington.amr.ch2m.com Vpxa: [FF98F780 verbose      'Default'] Set internal stats for VM: 7 (vpxa VM id), 444 (vpxd VM id). Is FT primary? 0",
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2014-05-27T20:48:35.492Z",
                "type" => "syslog",
                "host" => "paoli",
                "path" => "/var/log/rsyslog/lexington.amr.ch2m.com/Vpxa.log",
                "tags" => [
    [0] "_grokparsefailure"
],
```

As you can see in the message, the FQDN of the actual machine is listed just after the timestamp. However all of these messages show up in Elasticsearch/Kibana as coming from the loghost (paoli).

Once I can grep out the actual name I plan to tag the messages so I can do more with them.

Any assistance here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your current logstash configs? or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: Hi, I am basically pointing logstash at /var/log/rsyslog/**/*.log. It works great, I just want to see the logs as coming from the actual machine the log belongs to, not the loghost.

Comment: You need to parse your message. For example, get the FQDN from the message. Can you give the log format such that we can discuss how you parsing it.

Comment: Added the config I am using at the moment. Included what the output looks like as well. I am not seeing many example in searches of doing this, so wondering if I am doing it the hard way. Seems many configs don't need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Somehow I missed that I needed two logstash instances, one to feed into redis and another to read out of redis.

Every post/tutorial on this stack seems to become outdated quickly so I don't know if this is new or  just something I missed.